# Using range while fancy indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Can someone explain this expression to me in simple terms? How could you take a range of two values and set them to zero?

```
lena_image[range(xmax), range(ymax)] = 0
```

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: This expression will raise an error if `xmax != ymax`.

Answer (score 2):

`range(n)` generates a list ranging from `0` inclusive to `n` exclusive:

```
In [847]: range(3)
Out[847]: [0, 1, 2]
```

and numpy fancy indexing takes the elements at indices `X`s and `Y`s , and assign a new value to them:

```
In [856]: d
Out[856]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [857]: d[range(5), range(5)]=2 #assigns elems on diagonal d[0,0], d[1,1], d[2,2], etc.
     ...: print d
[[ 2.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  2.]]
```

**Note** that there must be the same numbers of `X`s and `Y`s in this case

If you want to modify a `block` (not diagonal this time), use *broadcasting*:

```
In [878]: arange(3)[:, None] #get a 2D array of shape (3, 1)
Out[878]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])

In [874]: d[arange(3)[:, None], arange(2)] #get the sub array of row 0~2, col 0~1
Out[874]: 
array([[ 2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])

In [875]: d[arange(3)[:, None], arange(2)]=100 #assign new values element-wise 

In [876]: d
Out[876]: 
array([[ 100.,  100.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 100.,  100.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [ 100.,  100.,    2.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    2.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    2.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will set the main diagonal to zero:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
lena_image = np.ones(shape=(n, n))
lena_image[range(n), range(n)] = 0
print lena_image
```

Out:

```
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]]
```