# Setting ranges to zero using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I began independently learning numpy using the numpy cookbook. I reviewed and executed the following code:

```
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot

#This script demonstates fancy indexing by setting values
#On the diagnols to 0

#Load lena array
lena = scipy.misc.lena()
xmax = lena.shape[0]
ymax = lena.shape[1]

#Fancy indexing
#can set ranges of points to zero, all at once instead of using loop
lena[range(xmax), range(ymax)] = 0
lena[range(xmax-1,-1,-1), range(ymax)] = 0
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(lena)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

I understand everything in this code except:

```
lena[range(xmax), range(ymax)] = 0
lena[range(xmax-1,-1,-1), range(ymax)] = 0
```

I read [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) on indexing and slicing but still cannot make sense of the above code. Here is are my points of confusion:

1)range(xmax) and range(ymax) encompass the entire x,y axes. Wouldn't setting them to zero make the entire image black?
2)What does range(xmax-1,-1,-1) mean?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Wasn't #1 explained in the answers to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963058/using-range-while-fancy-indexing)?  And #2 could be explained by `help(range)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bit of code is actually misleading, and relies on the fact that `lena` is a square image: what happens is equivalent to calling `zip(range(xmax), range(ymax))`, and then setting each of the resulting tuples to `0`.  You can see what could go wrong here: if `xmax != ymax`, then things won't work:

```
>>> test = lena[:,:-3]
>>> test.shape
(512, 509)
>>> xmax, ymax = test.shape
>>> test[range(xmax), range(ymax)] = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

It would probably be better to define `diag_max = min(xmax, ymax)`, and then set `lena[range(diag_max), range(diag_max)] = 0`.

The answer to your second question is easier:  `range(from, to, step)` is the general call to `range`:

```
>>> range(1, 10, 2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> range(1, 10, -2)
[]
>>> range(10, 1, -2)
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
>>> range(10, 0, -1)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

In particular, this reverses the previous list, and so grabs the diagonal from right to left instead of left to right.

Comment: " range(from, to, step) is the general call to range:"
Okay cool, I mixed up range() and list indexing (which uses semicolons). Thanks for clarifying that and the above

Answer (score 2):

'range' will give you a list. Try it in your REPL and see what happens:

```
r = range(5)
# r is no [0,1,2,3,4]
```

So doing 'lena[range(xmax), range(ymax)] = 0' will set the *diagonal* of the 'lena' matrix to zero since you're stepping through the x and y coordinates incrementally at the same time.

'range' is quite simple. The answer from @JLLagrange answers it perfectly.

Comment: "incrementally at the same time."
Ahh! That was a core concept I was missing. I didn't realize it was looping through both simultaneously. That makes a lot more sense! Thanks